# data recovery on ext4 partition

Tags: linux, partition, ext4, data-recovery, testdisk

this isn't a duplicate of previous similar questions. Hear me out ...alright. Thought the platform is android . The specific question pertains to  `ext4 data recovery`.

**Background** 
Just y'day ( aka < 24 hrs ) some process on my Android phone ( admittedly I lost my AT&T phone & till I could find another similar one - I used someone else's spare - turned out to be Xiaomi running MIUI.
Previous morning woke up to find  `/data/data/com.whatsapp/databases` ( &  I am `magiskcally rooted` ) folder truncated by some crapware ( like cleaner ? still trying to figure out ) that Xiaomi runs. The way  I always  have it - I have all my Imp apps write their stuff on 2nd partition of SD card which is `Ext4`.

```
/data/data/<selected app Name> ---> /data/sdext2/data/<selected app Name> 
/data/app/<selected app Name> ----> /data/sdext2/apk/<selected app Name>
```

Soon as I realized  - not too much time later - I unmounted my card and stuck it in my PC running live Linux. I used `extundelete ext4magic testdisk and R-studio` so I could locate that 1 `msgstore.db` file ( 1+ gb )

snippets of what I did

```
# tried various other ops including changing the `superblock`. Time based recovery and tinkered with various Util ops given  

ext4magic -a $t  -s 4096 -n $n -R -c -f data/com.whatsapp/databases -d `pwd` /dev/sdd2 

extundelete  --restore-directory data/com.whatsapp/databases --log ./extundelete.log /dev/sdd2
```

from both the above I could't get that  earlier instance of `/data/data/com.whatsapp/databases/msgstore.db` I was looking for . Other smaller though useless files could be recovered.
`R-studio`  p'much gave me the same stuff.  `Testdisk` a 4k directory.

ref to [this link right here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3883/how-to-recover-deleted-files) - pretty much everything has been tried.  No Luck. Deep Scans etc. 
How do I get back my database file. I strongly suspect an uninvited 'cleaner' app hosed my WhatsApp database file.
And I dont have recent backups. The one  I have  is  a tad old.  You'll say always backup. For some reason my Drive was full and I wasnt aware the nighty backup had'nt happened.

**Questions**

What else should I try. Given that the above supposedly powerful  utilities have dont squat - any luck with other Utils. I read about `scalpel` -would that do any a better ?

How do I get the exact time-stamp audit when the delete happened and the `inodes` involved and `sector / block numbers` . Is it poss to retrieve that way ?

 My understanding was that amongst all `filesystems` out there `ext4` being `journal`ed  is best when it comes to digging out deleted data - now I am banking on this .

Comment: I guess you did not let WhatsApp create automatic backups?

Comment: Journaling does not exist to facilitate undeletion. Its purpose is to prevent filesystem corruption, in case something happens to prevent pending writes from being completed. In fact, data loss is quite possible when a journal is recovered, as the priority is filesystem consistency. There are filesystems with features that do facilitate undeletion, but that doesn't help your situation. Plus, on an Android system, it's harder to change the filesystem anyway.

Comment: Pl read my Q sir. Its `ext4 linux partition` we are talking about not `android` . Think of an old trailer bus. `ext4` is the trailer that can be detached and `android` phone is the  drivers cabin & I just detached the trailer cos something inside it missing

Comment: Yes it was callous ( @Panki) -  I was falling short of space  & at my  convenience wd delete things I dont like. But right now  I want to know if I should have hopes of getting my data back.